# How to transfer names from .txt file to an array in a pre-defined variable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to transfer a list of names from a text file to a table/array in Ruby. The names look like this in the file:

```
Mandy
Sarah Jane
Melody
Ulrika
Katy Sue
```

Some names are one word and some two. I have a variable `@names` and I want to move them as an array into that variable. I also need to count how many names there are which I haven't been able to do at all!.

I have this:

```
defreadwordfile(filename)
file = file.open("names.txt","r")
file.each do |line|

contentsArray = []
file.each_line {|line|
contentArray.push line }

@names = contentArray
end

file.close
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend using proper indentation of your code. Also, your code isn't runnable which it should be. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: To fix your code: def readwordfile(filename); file = file.open("names.txt"); contentsArray = []; file.each { |line| contentArray.push(line.chomp) }; file.close; 
contentArray; end; @names = readwordfile(filename)`. Here the block variable `line` contains one line of the file. You therefore don't want `file.each_line {|line| ...`. You can include `"r"` as an argument of `open`, but if there is only one argument `"r"` is the default, so it's generally not included. Note where I've added `.chomp` to remove the line's newline character.

Comment: Your question is on hold, not closed. Edit it to clarify and the hold may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

```
contents  = IO.readlines(filename, chomp: true)
```

is all you need. See [IO::readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-c-readlines).

Comment: Hi Cary, Thanks very much for this. It does exactly what I want but after each name it puts \n is there a way to get just the name and not the \n? Thanks

Comment: Pengoo, please double-check that. The purpose of `chomp: true` is to remove the newlines. Try: `IO.write('t.txt', "dog\ncat\n"); IO.readlines('t.txt', chomp: true) #=> ["dog", "cat"]`. (You can replace `IO` with `File`, as is often done.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
names = IO.foreach("names.txt").with_object([]) do |line,array|
  array << line.strip
end

p names
#=> ["Mandy", "Sarah Jane", "Melody", "Ulrika", "Katy Sue"]
```

Assuming there's only one name or name/surname combination per line.

Not sure if it's a formatting issue in your question or there are actual empty lines in the file. If there are empty lines, and you want to ignore them you can replace the second line with this:

```
array << line.strip unless line.strip.empty?
```

This will ignore any lines that have no names/surnames.

While trying to edit your post I noticed names are between `<p>` `</p>` paragraph tags, not sure if this is intentional, but if you're trying to avoid those you can do it like this:

```
array << line.match(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/)[1]
```